# how can i pass variable value from a modal to next page

Tags: php

i am new to php programming and i have a modal where there is a link that will redirect you to the thread.
here's the code:

```
<a href="showthread.php?t=<?php echo $row['eventID'];?>">View Full Story</a><br>
```

how can i pass the value of $row['eventID'] to the page after i clicked the View Full Story link? i tried using this codes but it doesn't seem to work.
`<?php echo $_SESSION['eventID']=$row['eventID']; ?>` on the modal and then `<?php $id=$_SESSION['eventID']; echo $id; ?>`on the next page.

Comment: It should be `$_GET['t']` or do you want to use sessions? If you want to use sessions you need to start it everywhere.

Comment: You are using GET, so at the target page read the GET parameter and do what ever you want to do with it- $_GET['t']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an anchor tag with an `href` the `t` variable will be accessible as `$_GET['t']` in the `showthread.php` script

showthread.php

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_GET['t'] ) {
        echo $_GET['t'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: This approach will also be better because if you load 2 tabs at the same time your `$_SESSION['eventID']` would only hold the most recent request, and your second (or first depending on order) tab would load the wrong content.